# How do I enter values in the database?

Tags: woocommerce

I output the necessary WC object values using the class, I make changes to the input field, and I need to rewrite the values. Tell me, how can I do this?

```
<form>
<!-- Various input fields -->
<?php
$delivery_zones = WC_Shipping_Zones::get_zones();

foreach($delivery_zones[1]['shipping_methods'] as $zone_key=>$zone) { ?>
  <label>
    <?php echo $zone->method_title ?><span>*</span>
    <input type="number" value="<?php echo $zone->cost ?>"> // In this string
  </label>
<?php } ?>
<input type="submit" value="<?php echo $edit_action ? "Save" : "Add"; ?> Product">
</form>
```

Comment: You don't need only to store the value in the database, you need to refresh shipping cached data: Look in `wp_options` table searching for `%wc_shipping_method_count%` … All this data need to be updated too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<form>
<!-- Various input fields -->
<?php $delivery_zones = WC_Shipping_Zones::get_zones(); ?>

<?php foreach($delivery_zones[1]['shipping_methods'] as $zone_key=>$zone) { ?>
    <?php  $zone_title = mb_strtolower(str_replace(' ', '_', $zone->title));   ?>

    <label>
      <?php echo $zone->title ?><span>*</span>
      <input  id="product_shipping_method_<?php echo $zone_title ?>"
              type="number" 
              name="shipping_method_<?php echo $zone_title ?>"
              value="<?php echo $edit_action ? get_post_meta($product_id,'_shipping_method_' . $zone_title, true) : ""; ?>"/>
    </label>
<?php } ?>
  <input type="submit" value="<?php echo $edit_action ? "Save" : "Add"; ?> Product">
</form>
```

In the file with the functional, you need to update_post_meta:

```
$delivery_zones = WC_Shipping_Zones::get_zones();
foreach($delivery_zones[2]['shipping_methods'] as $zone_key=>$zone) {
    $zone_title = mb_strtolower(str_replace(' ', '_', $zone->title));
    update_post_meta($product_id, '_ed_shipping_method_' . $zone_title, $_POST['shipping_method_'.$zone_title]); 
}
```